# how to get header to show up on every page

Tags: wordpress, menu, header

I'm trying to get this header to show up on all the other pages on WordPress. How do I do this?

Pictures: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it uses a standard WordPress template :

Put all the data related to the header in the file below

```
header.php
```

and use function : get_header(); in other pages.

forexample :

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```